# Set or create embedded document in Mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, database

I have a a schema as follows:

```
/**
 * Answer Schema
 */
var AnswerSchema = new Schema({
  answer: Number,
  owner_id: Schema.Types.ObjectId
});

/**
 * Poll Schema
 */
var PollSchema = new Schema({
  question: { type: String, required: true, trim: true },
  choices: [ { type: String, required: true, trim: true} ],
  answers: [AnswerSchema]
});
```

How do I set an answer for a given poll_id and the owner_id of the person answering the poll?

Answer (score 0):

The term "set or create" sort of opens this up a bit.

Essentially you will **add** (create) new items in arrays using the [**`$push`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/push/) operator with `.update()`, or otherwise with a standard JavaScript array push once you have the current document after a `.find()`.

But considering you might want to "update" an existing answer for a given owner then it's possibly a two step operation. If not then you just want the "update" using the [**`$push`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/push/).

```js
PollSchema.update(
    { "_id": poll_id, "answers.owner_id": owner_id }
    { "$set":{ "answers.answer": value } },
    function(err,numAffected) {

       if (err)
          throw err;        // or whatever handling

       // If this didn't modify anything then $push a document
       if ( numAffected != 0 ) {
           PollSchema.update(
               { "_id": poll_id },
               { "$push": { 
                   "answers": { 
                       "owner_id": owner_id,
                       "answer": value
                   }
               }},
               function(err, numAffected) {
                  // more things in here
               }
           );

    }
);
```

Or again, if you do not care about having more than one answer per "owner" then just use the [**`$push`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/push/) update.